# Superposition calculus and ordering of equations

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, theorem-proving, first-order-logic

The superposition calculus is a theorem-proving technique that makes paramodulation less prolific by imposing a reduction ordering instead of applying every equation in both directions.

For a very simple test case, consider the following clauses (using notation where lower case letters denote constants not variables):

```
a=b
a=c
b!=c
```

Clearly it should be possible to deduce a contradiction from these clauses.

In this case we have only unit clauses of ground atomic terms, so the superposition rules can be stated in a greatly simplified form.

Superposition, left:

```
s=t, s!=v => t!=v
```

where `s > t`, `t >= v` in the chosen reduction ordering. (The full version of superposition needs to deal with clauses as multisets of literals, with variable substitutions, and with a reduction ordering that will only be total on ground terms, but these do not apply to the simple test case discussed here.)

Similarly,

Superposition, right:

```
s=t, s=v => t=v
```

where `s > t`, `t >= v` in the chosen reduction ordering.

Suppose we use the reduction ordering `a > b > c`. Then:

```
a=b, a=c => b=c
b=c, b!=c => false
```

However, the calculus needs to be complete for any choice of reduction ordering. Suppose instead `c > b > a`, then the first inference above is disallowed.

A candidate alternative inference:

```
c=a, c!=b => a=b
```

Also disallowed because `b > a`.

Alternative version:

```
c=a, c!=b => b=a
```

This entails trying the input equations in the direction allowed by the reduction ordering, then flipping the output equation around to likewise match the reduction ordering. When you do this, it works.

Is this allowed? In other words, is the intent of the definition of the superposition calculus, that equations are unordered, so each equation should be both generated and used in whichever order matches the reduction ordering?

Comment: Nice question. Would probably do better at [CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the record: In the standard theoretical expositions of the superposition calculus (my goto-paper is Leo Bachmair and Harald Ganzinger, "Rewrite-Based Equational Theorem Proving with Selection and Simplification", Journal of Logic and Computation, 1994, 3(4):217-247), all literals are equations or inequations. These are either explicitly defined as unordered pairs and then compared in a multiset-encoding, or they are directly defined as multisets (the exact details depend on which paper you read, but these are mostly just different descriptions of the same basic concept).

So yes, your assumption that equations are unordered is correct. All implementations I know of are inherently directional, and hence need to explicitly consider all orientations compatible with the term ordering.